# Is it allowed to create a paid Facebook client using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm planning to build an alternative Facebook client for Android using Facebook Android SDK.

And do we have to get an api key/token/whatever for the graph api first?

Comment: There are no API to get newsfeed so you can't

Comment: @WizKid are you sure? there are several facebook clients in play store and do launcher had facebook newsfeed option.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Read the documentation

Comment: @WizKid https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed O_o

Comment: @WizKid it shows posts of a user right? Can't we re-implement news feed algorithm?

Comment: It requires specific permission from the user, whom feed you want to fetch. So you can show the user of your app their own posts, but not their friends, unless they also use the app.

Comment: I think you can create a feed of pages' posts though - first fetch /user/likes and then /page/feed.

Comment: @MateuszBartkowiak we can get the posts by a user's friends and liked pages right? i was thinking that maybe i can reimplement the feed thing.

Comment: @Philosoraptor This may work for pages, but for users, according to the link you posted, you need user_posts permission. So you'd be able only to show posts from users, who logged to your app and gave permission.

Comment: @MateuszBartkowiak oh thank you